# Opposite of .contains (does not contain)

Tags: java, contains

I have an `if` statement:

```
if (inventory.contains("bread"))
```

But now I want to check

- if `inventory` contains "bread"
- but does not contain "water".

How can I do this?

Comment: `if(inventory.contains("bread") && !inventory.contains("water"))`?

Comment: Don't see why nobody mentioned that contains() returns a boolean so true if it contains the value or false if it doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewCarlson OP never asked such kind of thing.

Comment: I didn't say OP did, but if you have to ask how to check a boolean it would be helpful to note because op probably know what !boolean means.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It seems that `Luiggi Mendoza` and `joey rohan` both already answered this, but I think it can be clarified a little.

You can write it as a single `if` statement:

```
if (inventory.contains("bread") && !inventory.contains("water")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: As per clean code principle ! should be avoided in conditions. Ideal would be to extract !inventory.contains( ingredient ) should be extracted to a separate method e.g. boolean inventoryDoesNotHave(ingredient)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe

```
if (inventory.contains("bread") && !inventory.contains("water"))
```

Or

```
if (inventory.contains("bread")) {
    if (!inventory.contains("water")) {
        // do something here
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `if(!inventory.contains("water"))` for the second test.

Comment: You still have unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan for me it looks ok..won't you mind editing the answer?

Answer (score 0):

For your questions, use below

if(inventory.contains("bread") && !inventory.contains("water")) {

```
System.out.println("Bread is there and water not there");
```

}

else{

```
System.out.println("Both or any one condition not met");
```

}

Another example: Just use ! sign before contains function.

like if you want to perform some action, like if list does contains say stack then add stack.

```
   if (!list.contains("stack")) {
        list.add("stack");
    }`
```

or another method, if index of search string is -1,

```
 if(list.indexOf("stack")==-1){
    list.add("stack");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know we can use the '!' to get the opposite value of the String.contains() function. If you do not want to use the '!' symbol, use the following code:

```
if(inventory.contains("bread"))
{
    if(inventory.contains("water"))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        //do what you intend to do
    }
}
```

Comment: it is Ok but it is not a cleaner code than the second answer

Comment: Second answer also has "!" in the second if statement.